# In Laravel blade file, data not printed but in json format, data exist

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

While this issue is quite stupid, i am stuck as for a variable data exist in JSON response but not i'm able to print it in blade.

I have a record for schedule message:

Here I want to display the message issue, so i'm using eloquent here.
I have group record set up for the scheduled message.

While i'm able to print the group name with id, the same code for message issue won't work.

We can see the data if i do as below in blade:

```php
{{ $schedule_message }}
```

Output:

```php
{ 
   "id":28,
   "group_id":73,
   "issue_id":2,
   "title":"Et eum quibusdam ut delectus.",
   "content":"Sunt inventore ea quisquam at repudiandae error. Qui soluta iusto voluptates sint quo est tempore impedit.",
   "url":"https:\/\/www.google.com",
   "trigger_at":"2019-11-26 18:12:57",
   "day":"26th Nov, 2019",
   "time":"18:12:57 PM",
   "type":1,
   "status":1,
   "creator_id":44,
   "moderator_id":48,
   "created_at":"2019-11-26 09:32:17",
   "updated_at":"2019-11-26 09:32:17",
   "deleted_at":null,
   "group":{ 
      "id":73,
      "name":"Wable, Krish and Deo"
   },
   "issue":{ 
      "id":2,
      "title":"Arthritis"
   },
   "creator":{ 
      "id":44,
      "name":"Heer Mukherjee"
   },
   "moderator":{ 
      "id":48,
      "name":"Rupesh Ganesan"
   }
}
```

But if i do this in blade, I get blank/noting/null:

```php
{{ $schedule_message->issue }}
```

For testing: if I do this in blade, it works:

```php
{{ $schedule_message->group }}
```

Output:

```php
{"id":73,"name":"Wable, Krish and Deo"}
```

Database structure is the same. Eloquent code is same. Even if I get the output as JSON, then whats wrong in blade file?

---

Controller code added below:

```php
ScheduleMessage::with(['group','issue', 'creator', 'moderator'])->latest()->paginate(env('REC_LIMIT'));
```

Comment: please put your comtroller code.

Comment: Please post the code of your controller and models.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, it was not working unless I ran `php artisan cache:clear`. that's totally weard for me :/ still I have included the controller code now in the post. model code is fine as I am getting data for the group before cache clearing. and issue function is dido of group function with just table name changed.